# Polynomial : holonomic :: rational function :?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, terminology

A sequence $(a_n)$ is called *holonomic* if it can be specified with initial terms and a recurrence
$$
a_n=P_1(n)a_{n-1}+P_2(n)a_{n-2}+\cdots+P_k(n)a_{n-k}
$$
where $k$ is an integer and $P_1,\ldots,P_k$ are polynomials. Is there a term for the generalization in which the $P_i$ are allowed to be rational functions rather than polynomials? If so, does anyone have a pointer to a reference describing their properties?